# Which Rig-Vedic Gods have spouses who are also mentioned in the Rig Veda Samhita?

Tags: gods, rig-veda

Famous spouses Lakshmi and Parvati don't occur in Rig Veda Samhita, as far as I know.

Which Gods also have their spouses mentioned in the Rg Veda Samhita?

Comment: Lakshmi is mentioned in the Sri Sukta of the Rig Veda Samhita.

Comment: Lakshmi was mentioned in Khilas , an appendix to Rig Veda, is a later day addition but not a part of core Rig Veda. Sri Sukta is from Khilas

Comment: the Sanskrit of sri sukta is at least a 1000 years younger than that of the rig veda samhita.  anyway, I changed the question to focus only on the samhita portion.

Answer (score 1):

There are many instances of references to the wives of the Devas in Rig Veda. I shall give one or two instances of each.

**Indrāṇī and Varuṇānī**
RV 2.32.8:

> या गुङ्गूर्या सिनीवाली या राका या सरस्वती । इन्द्राणीमह्व ऊतये वरुणानीं स्वस्तये ॥

**Indrāṇī, Varuṇānī, Agnāyī and Aśvinī**
RV 5.46.8:

> उत ग्ना व्यन्तु देवपत्नीरिन्द्राण्यग्नाय्यश्विनी राट् । आ रोदसी वरुणानी शृणोतु व्यन्तु देवीर्य ऋतुर्जनीनाम् ॥

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer

---

Rig Veda [6.66.3](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06066.htm) says that Maruts are the sons of Pṛśni.

> They who are Sons of the rain-pouring Rudra, whom the long-lasting One
>   had power to foster: The Mighty Ones whose germ great Mother Pṛśni is
>   known to have received for man's advantage.

So Rudra and Pṛśni are couples.

---

Indra and Sachi are another couple mentioned in Rig Veda. ( **Source yet to be mentioned**)

---

In Rig Veda [I.185.2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01185.htm) Heaven and Earth were mentioned as Divine parents.

> bhūriṃ dve acarantī carantaṃ padvantaṃ gharbhamapadī dadhāte | nityaṃ
>   na sūnuṃ ***pitrorupasthe dyāvā rakṣataṃ pṛthivī*** no abhvāt ||
>
> The Twain uphold, though motionless and footless, a widespread
>   offspring having feet and moving. Like your own son upon his parents’
>   bosom, protect us, Heaven and earth, from fearful danger.

Answer (score -1):

## Famous spouses Lakshmi and Parvati don't occur in Rig Veda Samhita, as far as I know.

Laxmi is mentioned in Rigveda.

- Rigveda 10:71:2

> सक्तुमिव तितउना पुनन्तो यत्र धीरा मनसा वाचमक्रत । अत्रा सखायः सख्यानि जानते भद्रैषां **लक्ष्मी** र्निहिताधि वाचि॥२॥

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakshmi)

Parvati is mentioned in other Upanishads.

-

Comment: What you quoted as Rigveda 1:43:2, is not from Rig Veda, please check [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01043.htm). Similarly, with [Rigveda 1:35:21](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01035.htm) They may be from Yajur Veda @SanatanDarshan

Comment: Thanks @srimannarayana k v - rig veda 1:35 has only 11 verses - and the language cited is so young it is either epic or puranic.  this is very sad that people post false things  - one can only hope that this gentleman would correct his errors.  even what is cited as RV 1:43 is in epic/puranic sanskrit.

Comment: @SK sorry it is because of some misunderstanding. I will correct it.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I will correct my mistake

Comment: you still haven't fully corrected your mistake @Sanatan Darshan   The Lakshmi you cite is not Vishnu's spouse.  "Rama" and "Sita" occur in Rig Veda but they are not the ones written about in Ramayana.

Comment: @SK in the question it is written that Parvati and Laxmi are not mentioned in Vedas so I am answering it

Comment: @SK we can't consider that either they are or not.

Comment: whatever you say @Sanatan Darshan.  The question is not about the WORD Lakshmi, but Lakshmi as Vishnu's spouse.  I'll ignore you from here on - this is absurd.